# How to create correct HTML5 documents that use maps?

Tags: html

I'm considering this example from the HTML5 specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#image-maps

```
<p>
 Please select a shape:
 <img src="shapes.png" usemap="#shapes"
      alt="Four shapes are available: a red hollow box, a green circle, a blue triangle, and a yellow four-pointed star.">
 <map name="shapes">
  <area shape=rect coords="50,50,100,100"> <!-- the hole in the red box -->
  <area shape=rect coords="25,25,125,125" href="red.html" alt="Red box.">
  <area shape=circle coords="200,75,50" href="green.html" alt="Green circle.">
  <area shape=poly coords="325,25,262,125,388,125" href="blue.html" alt="Blue triangle.">
  <area shape=poly coords="450,25,435,60,400,75,435,90,450,125,465,90,500,75,465,60"
        href="yellow.html" alt="Yellow star.">
 </map>
</p>
```

My concern is that [map](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-map-element) is a transparent element.

[Transparent](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#transparent) means that by removing the corresponding opening and closing tags, the document must still be correct.

That is, the following fragment has to be correct.

```
<p>
 Please select a shape:
 <img src="shapes.png" usemap="#shapes"
      alt="Four shapes are available: a red hollow box, a green circle, a blue triangle, and a yellow four-pointed star.">
  <area shape=rect coords="50,50,100,100"> <!-- the hole in the red box -->
  <area shape=rect coords="25,25,125,125" href="red.html" alt="Red box.">
  <area shape=circle coords="200,75,50" href="green.html" alt="Green circle.">
  <area shape=poly coords="325,25,262,125,388,125" href="blue.html" alt="Blue triangle.">
  <area shape=poly coords="450,25,435,60,400,75,435,90,450,125,465,90,500,75,465,60"
        href="yellow.html" alt="Yellow star.">
</p>
```

However, the context in which the [area](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-area-element) element can be used is as a map or template descendant. That means that the `<p> ... </p>` *has* to be surrounded by some template element.

However the template element description is:

> The template element is used to declare fragments of HTML that can be cloned and inserted in the document by script.

which seems unrelated to image maps ...

How to create correct HTML5 documents that use maps?

Edit: An answer that just got deleted leveraged an interesting point : According to the W3C validator, [the above document is correct](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&acceptlanguage=&doc=data%3Atext%2Fhtml%3Bcharset%3Dutf-8%2C%253C%21DOCTYPE%20html%253E%250D%250A%253Ctitle%253ETest%253C%252Ftitle%253E%250D%250A%253Cp%253E%250D%250A%20Please%20select%20a%20shape%253A%250D%250A%20%253Cimg%20src%253D%22shapes.png%22%20usemap%253D%22%2523shapes%22%250D%250A%20alt%253D%22Four%20shapes%20are%20available%253A%20a%20red%20hollow%20box%252C%20a%20green%20circle%252C%20a%20blue%20triangle%252C%20and%20a%20yellow%20four-pointed%20star.%22%253E%250D%250A%20%253Cmap%20name%253D%22shapes%22%253E%250D%250A%20%253Carea%20shape%253Drect%20coords%253D%2250%252C50%252C100%252C100%22%253E%20%253C%21--%20the%20hole%20in%20the%20red%20box%20--%253E%250D%250A%20%253Carea%20shape%253Drect%20coords%253D%2225%252C25%252C125%252C125%22%20href%253D%22red.html%22%20alt%253D%22Red%20box.%22%253E%250D%250A%20%253Carea%20shape%253Dcircle%20coords%253D%22200%252C75%252C50%22%20href%253D%22green.html%22%20alt%253D%22Green%20circle.%22%253E%250D%250A%20%253Carea%20shape%253Dpoly%20coords%253D%22325%252C25%252C262%252C125%252C388%252C125%22%20href%253D%22blue.html%22%20alt%253D%22Blue%20triangle.%22%253E%250D%250A%20%253Carea%20shape%253Dpoly%20coords%253D%22450%252C25%252C435%252C60%252C400%252C75%252C435%252C90%252C450%252C125%252C465%252C90%252C500%252C75%252C465%252C60%22%250D%250A%20href%253D%22yellow.html%22%20alt%253D%22Yellow%20star.%22%253E%250D%250A%20%253C%252Fmap%253E%250D%250A%253C%252Fp%253E) when only surrounded with the usual HTML boilerplate.

Comment: Yeah I deleted my answer because somebody else had almost immediately downvoted it. I have no idea why. Anyway, if you want, I’m happy to re-post an answer with further elaboration. But the gist of it is that the first markup example in the question is valid per all HTML spec requirements, and the second one isn’t—and doesn’t need to be because you’re not saying you want to actually use that second markup example anyway.

Comment: Yeah, but is this a bug in the validator or an error in the specification? Because the two do not agree ...

Comment: It’s not a bug in either the spec nor the validator. The spec doesn’t say “by removing the corresponding opening and closing tags, the document must still be correct”, and from the actual spec requirements it doesn’t follow at all that just because the first markup example in the question is valid, the second markup example (with the map element completely removed) must also be valid. That’s not what the spec means by “transparent”.

Comment: The spec may sometimes be unclear, but IMHO what they mean by transparent is very clear ... The content model is exported ^^ (https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#transparent)

Comment: Now if interpretation is required in order to read the spec, then its another story, but this does not make the job of people building HTML libraries easy ... :-(